# Google Cloud Container Registry - Check image size

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-registry

I sent a docker file for Google Cloud Build. The build was created successfully.

The artifact URL is:

> gcr.io/XXX/api/v1:abcdef017e651ee2b713828662801b36fc2c1

How I can check the image size? (MB\GB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't API for this. But I have a workaround, this Linux command line

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
  https://gcr.io/v2/XXX/api/v1/manifests/abcdef017e651ee2b713828662801b36fc2c1 2>/dev/null | \
  jq ".layers[].size" | \
  awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'
```

Detail line by line

1. Create a curl with a secure token from the GCLOUD CLI
2. Get the image manifest, which describe all the layers and their size
3. Get only the layers' sizes
4. Sum the sizes

-> Result is in Byte.

Comment: Not working for me. I replaced the image url (`https://gcr.io/...`) with my equivalent and saw  that your value is different then my original value. Where is the `v2` section is coming from?

Comment: v2 is the manifest version. Here you simply use the [DOCKER API](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#manifest) It's not Google specific APIs